# How to stop a Text view in a ZStack from adding vertical padding when placed in a VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I add a Text view in a ZStack it adds vertical padding to the view, and can be seen in a VStack or a LazyVGrid. Specifically, I have a CardView struct that shows just a colored RoundedRectangle initially, and when you tap on this RoundedRectangle it "flips" and shows a white RoundedRectangle, with a colored .strokeBorder, and then some Text in a ZStack. Only when this card is "flipped" and showing Text does the vertical padding show and differ from the other non-flipped cards that are just showing the colored RoundedRectangle.

When I add a .padding(.vertical, 0.1), or some other small number for the vertical padding on the ZStack, the difference in padding between showing the text and not showing the text goes away, which is good, but this doesn't seem like a good solution. Also, when removing the Text from the flipped version of the card the random padding also goes away. I've also already tried adding `spacing: 0` to the VStack but that's not fixing the issue.

The code is below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var contents = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    @State var contentCount = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]) {
                    ForEach(contents[0..<contentCount], id: \.self) { content in
                        CardView(content: content).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                }.foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            HStack {
                removeButton
                Spacer()
                addButton
            }.font(.largeTitle).padding(.horizontal).foregroundColor(.blue)
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    var removeButton: some View {
        Button {
            if contentCount > 1 {
                contentCount -= 1
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
        }
    }
    
    var addButton: some View {
        Button {
            if contentCount < contents.count {
                contentCount += 1
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
        }
        
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    @State var isFaceUp: Bool = true
    var content: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 5)
                Text(content).font(.largeTitle)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
        //.padding(.vertical, 0.000001) // <- This removes the unwanted padding when flipped.
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```

You can also see the issue if you add two CardViews to the top of the first VStack in ContentView. I am new to SwiftUI, so I'm not really sure of a lot of options, and the [course](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/) I'm following doesn't run into this issue, and is using an older version of SwiftUI but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it, but it seems that adding and removing the Text from the CardView is what's causing the issue. I'm not sure of any modifiers that can stop that from happening.

[image: Image of the issue]

You can see that the rows in the LazyVGrid that have the cards flipped up, showing the Text, have added a vertical space to the whole row, and the rows without the Text have no vertical spacing. If you were to do this with just single CardViews in a VStack, the same thing would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my own question. Adding `spacing:` arguments to the `LazyVGrid` and the `GridItem`s allowed me to control both the horizontal and vertical spacings of each `CardView`.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65), spacing: 8)], spacing: 8) {
                    ForEach(contents[0..<contentCount], id: \.self) { content in
                        CardView(content: content).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the ideal way, but it certainly seems like a good solution.

It does seem like the horizontal spacing of the `GridItem` had a default value that didn't change in this scenario, but I'm not sure how to get the vertical spacing to be the same default as whatever that value is, but 8 for both seemed good.